# AngularJS Provider and Global Variables Access

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS Provider as follows

```
myApp.provider('myProvider', function () {

    this.setbaseUrl = function (url) {
        var baseUrl = url + /api/v1/;
        return baseUrl;
    };
    this.$get = function () {
      return this;
    };
  });
```

All is good there and i injected it successfully to myApp.config and can return the value of baseUrl.

But how do i access the baseUrl value from a `service`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make get url function for it and define baseUrl as global

```
var baseUrl;
this.setbaseUrl = function (url) {
        baseUrl = url + /api/v1/;

    };

this.getbaseUrl=function(){
    return baseUrl;
}
```

Comment: That is i am certain a newbie question, but upon when i add `myProvider` in the service like in `myApp.service('MySrvc', function(myProvider){});` and call getbaseUrl it does not work same happens when i add `my` only without Provider. What am i missing?

Comment: Could you paste your code on fiddle.net, it is easy to understand your problem.